# Binding a textBlock text to a value in a custom class xaml c#

Tags: c#, xaml

when i navigate to the new page where it should display the text, it appears empty

The Xaml code i have

```
  xmlns:vm="using:Estimation" 

  <Page.DataContext>
    <vm:PlayerClass/>
  </Page.DataContext>
```

this is the textBlock im trying to bind the data too.

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="PlayerOne"
             Text="{Binding PlayerOneName}" 
               />
```

The Class im binding is as follows

```
 public class PlayerClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }

    private string name;
    public string PlayerOneName { get { return this.name; }
                                  set { this.name = value ;
                            NotifyPropertChanged(PlayerOneName); } }

}}
```

and the class im changing the content in the text box is

```
        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
             if (PlayerOneTextBox.Text == EnterNameText ||
            PlayerTwoTextBox.Text == EnterNameText ||
                 PlayerThreeTextBox.Text == EnterNameText ||
            PlayerFourTextBox.Text == EnterNameText)
        {
            MessageDialog msgBox = new MessageDialog("Please Enter All Names Before Continuing");
            msgBox.ShowAsync();

        }
        else
        {
            //   playerNames.PropertyChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(playerNames_PropertyChanged);
           this.DataContex.PlayerOneName = PlayerOneTextBox.Text;
            MessageDialog msgBox = new MessageDialog(playerNames.PlayerOneName);
            msgBox.ShowAsync();


            playerNames.PlayerTwoName = PlayerTwoTextBox.Text;
            playerNames.PlayerThreeName = PlayerTwoTextBox.Text;
            playerNames.PlayerFourName = PlayerFourTextBox.Text;
           Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewRoundPage));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor set the name

```
public PlayerClass ()
{
   PlayerOneName = "Jabba De Hutt";
}
```

Also set a fallback value to provide an indicator of a failed binding situation:

```
Text="{Binding PlayerOneName, FallBack=Unknown}"
```

The navigate should not change the datacontext of the textbox, change the viewmodel instead

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
      var  PlayerNames = e.Parameter as PlayerClass;

      this.DataContext.PlayerOneName = PlayerNames.PlayerOneName;

   }
```